# How to check if an object is alloced or not?

Tags: objective-c

Is there anyway to check if an object is alloced or not?  Thanks.

Edit:  Here's a better question.  Is it ok to alloc an object that was already alloced without changing it's initial value?

Comment: There is no such thing as an unalloced object. An object is what results from calling `alloc` on a class. Did you mean, perhaps, whether a pointer refers to an alloced object?

Comment: An example would be good to understand your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may intend how to check if a pointer points to an allocated object (which, as long as it stays in memory, is referenced by an unique memory address). In that case you could test if that pointer is `nil` in an *if statement* (or simply call is name in the condition, since objective-C inherits from C the evaluation of truth conditions, ie if it is *not* zero than it is true)

Comment: I have tried that, but the complier says that the object is undeclared.

Comment: You have not declared the pointer probably. Post your code so we can help you

Comment: Something like this.  
if (&theButtonCount == nil)
{
    ButtonCount *ButtonCount = [[PiCount alloc] init];
}

Comment: `theButtonCount` is not defined, you only defined `ButtonCount` plus you shall not use the deferencing operator `&` (and I also hope that ButtonCount is a superclass for PiCount). Just declare the pointer as `MYClass * pointer;` or `MYClass *pointer = nil;` and then `if (pointer != nil)` or `if (pointer)`

Answer (score 1):

No. You can check whether an object is *initialised* assuming you control the object, by having it change its state once it's fully initialised. However an *alloced* object is just a block of memory with a pointer at the start. The only possible test would yield too many false positives.

Another way to look at it is this: there is no such thing as an object that has not been alloced.